# EF 5 benchmarks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, ibatis, dapper

I'm following the [performance test](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Tests/PerformanceTests.cs) that Dapper community created.

Currently, I'm getting the following after run the tests 10000 times:

- EF 5 = 21595 ms
- ADO.NET = 52183 ms
- Dapper = 52499 ms
- iBatis = 83138 ms

I need that something help me to understand why EF is faster.
**What did I do wrong?**

The code that I'm using is on [Github](https://github.com/AugustoPedraza/orm-comparation)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, EF did definitely get faster: they invested a lot of time improving perf - by most of my measures, it still has noticeable overhead. Consider: EF sits on top of ADO.NET. If EF is reporting results that are significantly *faster* than ADO.NET, then (and I think you already suspect this): you aren't measuring what you *think* you are measuring.

I *suspect* the key issue here is that you are performing all the operations on the same data-context. This means you are probably now just stressing the identity manager and cache. I can't run your code directly (because it uses Oracle etc), but it would be interesting to view  the actual queries that are performed. In real world usage, each data-context has a finite unit-of work lifetime. It would be incredibly rare to execute 10,000 operations on the same data-context. More typical would be a handful of operations.

However, unrelated: I have to say: I'm *very* pleased with your results showing dapper as being within 0.6% of raw ADO.NET performance. This is basically exactly what we were going for with dapper: the full performance of raw ADO.NET, but simply taking away the coding pain.